# TensorFlow install on Windows 10, Github instructions for pip3 vague or not working

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation

I'm long past my coding days, but I'm dealing with higher level machine learning issues and thought I'd glance at a few TensorFlow tutorials.

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows are the instructions I'm following the CPU instructions. I've installed Python 3.6.4 w/o a problem. Now I'm onto the "start a terminal". I've tried the pip3 command in a Python terminal, a DOS cmd prompt and in the PowerShell. I've copy and pasted the exact text, all fail to see "pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow" as a valid command.

As the install page doesn't mention a download, is it correct to assume that Python is supposed to know to go to github to start the install, or am I supposed to download something not mentioned and then point the pip3 instruction towards the download?

Comment: I had the same problem. This is the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48720940/3090807