# i am unable to setup TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

im attempting to setup tensorflow but once I run the command: `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow`
(the command is for non-nvidia GPUs (like my AMD GPU) as listed on the site: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) 
but i get this error:

```
'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

i have python 3.6 installed and Anaconda 3 (the requirements and it didn't work).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installation of TensorFlow on windows 7 - 'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42559222/installation-of-tensorflow-on-windows-7-pip3-is-not-recognized-as-an-interna)

Comment: You should probably be using conda to install tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

try `python -m pip install --upgrade tensorflow`.

[credit to @LechMigdal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42559222/installation-of-tensorflow-on-windows-7-pip3-is-not-recognized-as-an-interna)

Comment: in CMD or Python Terminal?

Comment: In CMD! Let me know results

Comment: C:\>python -m pip install --upgrade tensorflow
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Interesting. Can you get into the python interpreter from CMD?

Comment: another thing to try: `py -m pip install --upgrade tensorflow`

Comment: whats python interpreter? (sorry if its common knowledge i use 'brackets' mostly)

Comment: No problem! Python interpreter is essentially a program you can enter from the command line that will take in commands line by line and behave as a live python program. More info can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html)

Comment: This seems like it's a problem with your PATH variable, which can be pretty annoying. If `py -m pip install --upgrade tensorflow` doesn't work, try doing what @rajesh outlines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43937364/4514236)