# Error Installing TENSORFLOW using PIP

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, pip

When I try to install Tensorflow by typing "pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow" into the C: command prompt line, I get the error: "pip3 is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" (See attached picture)

I have Python 3.6.5 installed on my Windows 7 laptop, so it includes "pip3" needed to install Tensorflow.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installation of TensorFlow on windows 7 - 'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42559222/installation-of-tensorflow-on-windows-7-pip3-is-not-recognized-as-an-interna)

Answer (score 0):

Since your computer *does* have Python 3.6 and it comes with *pip*, you could try running

```
python -mpip install tensorflow
```

If Python isn't found either, run

```
c:\python36\bin\python -mpip install tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that "pip3" is not recognized as a command. In order for pip to be run from the command line, it needs to be added to your system's PATH.

The accepted answer here should help:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command