# python winapi installation on 3.65

Tags: python, winapi, python-3.6

I need to use `winapi` for a project and I must use `python 3.6` to do so.

I have two interpreters installed: `python 3.65` and `python 2.7` (the original).
Whenever I use the `pip install pypiwin32` command it tells me it is already installed on the `2.7` version. When I tried to move the files from the `2.7` directory to the `3.65` directory it wouldn't work.

How do I install `winapi` on `python 3.65`?

Comment: Usually, for *Python3*, it's *pip3* (but you also need to have in your *%PATH%*). Did you try using it with the full path (e.g. *"C:\Program Files\Python\36\Scripts\pip3.exe"* ...)? That way there's no room left for confusion. Also what is *winapi*? Are you talking about *pywin32*?

Answer (score 2):

When you have multiple Pythons installed, and you don’t want to use virtual environments, the best solution is to run `pip` this way:

```
$ python3 -m pip install spam
```

Or, on Windows, using the `py` launcher:

```
C:\> py -3 -m pip install spam
```

Or, if you normally run Python 3.6 with some totally different command, same thing:

```
$ /opt/local/python36/bin/python -m pip install spam
```

As long as you know how to run the Python version you want to run, you can run it with `-m pip`, and that way you can be sure you’re getting the `pip` that goes with that Python version, and installing packages into that Python version’s site library.

All that being said, is there a reason you don’t want to use virtual environments? It would make your life a lot easier in this case.

Comment: It says it installed successfully, however python doesn't recognize the package.

Answer (score 0):

When there are both versions of `python` installed (`2.x` and `3.x`), the command `pip3` should be available to target the newer version.

You could try

```
pip3 install pypiwin32
```

Let us know how it goes.

Comment: "'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: That's what it says.

Comment: @Ofir Which OS are you using? Windows?

Comment: Yes I use windows.

Comment: @Ofir what does it say when you use the commands `python --version` and `python3 --version`? If they dont work, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48720940/9225671) for steps to add python to your system path.